# Forma de controlar la distribución con Bootstrap y CSS

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo una prueba, construyendo una aplicación que tiene un menú lateral y el contenido a su derecha. Intencionadamente he puesto un contenido de texto muy largo, para ver que está correctamente conectada la parte del menú y la del contenido (no se desplazan conjuntamente).

Efectivamente funciona. Pero he tenido que controlar cada div, para que vaya ocupando el 100% y poner una barra de desplazamiento lateral cuando el contenido tiene overflow.

El problema es que voy a utilizarlo con Angular, y este framework muchas veces crea div adicionales que no voy a poder controlar. ¿Se os ocurre una forma de hacerlo sin utilizar display: flex?

styles.css

```
html, body, 
    .container-fluid, .row, #menu, #contenido{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

#menu{
    background-color: blue;
}

#contenido{
    background-color: white;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

ul li:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- CSS propio -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <title>CSS Playground</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Contenido de mi página -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
              <div id="menu" class="col-md-4 py-3">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Opción 1</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Opción 2</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Opción 3</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Opción 4</li>
                </ul>                   
              </div>

              <div id="contenido" class="col-md-8 py-3 px-3">
                  ... Aquí iba un texto de 10.000 caracteres ...
              </div>
         </div>   
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

He intentado cambiar en el CSS la selección de lo que ocupa el 100% de la siguiente manera, pero no funciona. Bajan tanto el menú como la parte de texto.

```
html, body, 
    .div{
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Muchas gracias,

Comment: ¿Dónde añade Angualr esos div adicionales y que efecto indeseado producen? Un ejemplo sería ideal.

Comment: Por ejemplo, todos los componentes cuelgan de un componente raiz app-component. Dentro de este va colgando toda la jerarquía de componentes, estando además contenido cada parte de html en cada etiqueta que encapsula cada componente etc.